# MVC 4 routing / controller logic - something basic going wrong

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, view, asp.net-mvc-routing, asp.net-mvc-views

I had this working yesterday and why it has stopped working is completely beyond me. I have the following, basic scenario:

There are two types of roles in my application, Tenant and Landlord. When a Tenant logs in they should be directed to the Tenant profile page, the same goes for Landlord (at the moment I'm only working with Tenants).

Here's the workflow of the scenario:

1. A user logs in via `_LoginPartial`, I'm sure the logic in the partial is correct, but for some reason SO won't let me propertly paste the razor code in here...
2. Clicking the log in button calls the `Login` `ActionResult` in the `AccountController`. The method validates the user and checks to see what role they are in. If the user is in role Tenant they should be redirected to the `MyProfile` `ActionResult` in the `TenantsController`. Code for `Login`:

   ```
   public ActionResult Login(LoginModel model)
   {
       if (ModelState.IsValid && WebSecurity.Login(model.UserName, model.Password, persistCookie: model.RememberMe))
       {
           if (Roles.IsUserInRole("Tenant"))
           {
               return RedirectToAction("MyProfile", "Tenants");
           }
       }

       // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
       ModelState.AddModelError("", "The user name or password provided is incorrect.");
       return View(model);
   }
   ```
3. Upon being invoked `MyProfile` should display the user's profile. Code for `MyProfile` `ActionResult`:

   ```
   public ActionResult MyProfile()
   {
       var db = new LetLordContext();
       var currentTenant = db.UserProfile.First(t => t.UserName == HttpContext.User.Identity.Name);

       return View(currentTenant);
   }
   ```

As I said this was working yesterday, but I get the following error when I click the login button on `_RegisterPartial`:

> The view 'Login' or its master was not found or no view engine supports the searched locations. The following locations were searched:
>   ~/Views/Account/Login.aspx
>   ~/Views/Account/Login.ascx
>   ~/Views/Shared/Login.aspx
>   ~/Views/Shared/Login.ascx
>   ~/Views/Account/Login.cshtml
>   ~/Views/Account/Login.vbhtml
>   ~/Views/Shared/Login.cshtml
>   ~/Views/Shared/Login.vbhtml

Why is MVC looking for a view called Login? I havn't specified it to route to a view called Login. Is there something wrong with my routing/controller logic? Help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Have you debuged the code till this line?.....
return RedirectToAction("MyProfile", "Tenants");

Comment: The 'if' isn't being satisfied when I debug, the roles don't seem to be there for some reason - they were yesterday.

Comment: yeah, that is why i provided you the code in my answer to test whether it is satisfying if or not :)
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was being caused by using this...

```
if (Roles.IsUserInRole("Tenant"))
```

...instead of this:

```
if (Roles.IsUserInRole(model.UserName, "Tenant"))
```

The former can be called after a user is logged in. It seems the latter has to be used when called inside `Login` - may have something to with the user not being in the session / fully logged in etc.

It works anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Because these lines are executed:

```
// If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
ModelState.AddModelError("", "The user name or password provided is incorrect.");
return View(model);
```

Apparently either login attempt failed, or input was invalid. Now the last return of the `Login` action is executed. Since you have not stated the view's name directly, the naming convention tries to find view with the same name as the action (Login in this case). Try specifying View name explicitly:

```
return View("ViewName", model);
```

Comment: The login credential are definitely valid. I now understand why I'm getting that error, thanks. Can you see anything wrong with what I'm trying to do before the error - given that I know the login credentials are correct?

Comment: @MattSull87, might there be any changes with roles? If condition in `if` is not satisfied for some reason (e.g. logged in user is not a Tenant) redirect won't happen as well.

Comment: I'm thinking it must be that too - I've debugged and when it gets to the 'if' I can't see the roles I've defined... I'll look into it more, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your `Login` action of `AccountsController` returns a `View(model)`.

By convention, MVC will look for a view name matching the action name in the folder matching the controller name. Hence it is looking for Login view under Accounts controller.

Comment: Thanks, I understand why I'm getting that error. Can you see anything else wrong with my logic - given that I know login credentials are correct?

Comment: Since you have a _LoginPartial, can you return that partial view with the model errors in it? Login credentials being correct is a runtime behaviour, the error that you see will come up at compile time. Also, in case your login credentials are wrong, you still need to handle it.

Answer (score 0):

Do the following trick and check if it prints "Hello User" on the browser, if yes then it means that it is not validating the user and redirecting to login page as mentioned at the bottom of your method.

```
public ActionResult Login(LoginModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid && WebSecurity.Login(model.UserName, model.Password, persistCookie: model.RememberMe))
    {
        if (Roles.IsUserInRole("Tenant"))
        {
            return RedirectToAction("MyProfile", "Tenants");
        }
    }

    // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
    ModelState.AddModelError("", "The user name or password provided is incorrect.");
    return Content("Hello User");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Open your web.config.

Look here:

```
<system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" timeout="2880" />
    </authentication>
```

Comment: Could you give me more information as to what exactly this will achieve?

Comment: Sorry, should have explained more. Look in your web.config and just make sure it's not pointing to that View at this location. I've had this happen once, and this was the issue. It's just a single thing to confirm is pointing to the correct place. Or perhaps I misunderstood the problem.